# TCHart - get number of points I have added to a series

Tags: delphi, c++builder

I am using `Chart1.Series[0].AddXY()` to add points to a chart.

Sine I will add each new point one X-axis pixel after the last, I thought I could use something like  `Chart1.Series[0].AddXY(Chart1.Series[0].NumSampleValues, codValue, '', clRed );`  but, for some reason, `Chart1.Series[0].NumSampleValues` always evaluates to 26.

I guess I am using the wrong property. Which should I be using?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you should not use `NumSampleValues`

If you want to add at the last (provided that you are incrementing X-axis by 1) you can use `Series1.XValues.Count`;

Answer (score 2):

What about `TChartSeries.Count`?

> TChartSeries.Count TChartSeries
>
> function Count: Integer;
>
> Unit TeEngine
>
> Description This function returns the
>   number of points in the Series.

And just for completeness: This is what `NumSampleValues` does:

> Each Series draws random values at
>   design mode unless you connect the
>   Series component to other Series
>   component or to a DataSet
>   (Table,SQL,TClientDataset) component.
>
> This virtual function returns the
>   predefined number of random values
>   each Series draws.